# NLP: Calculating probability a document belongs to a topic (with a bag of words)?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Given a topic, how can I calculate the probability a document "belongs" to that topic(ie sports)

This is what I have to work with:

1) I know the common words in documents associated with that topics (eliminating all STOP words), and the % of documents that have that word 
For instance if the topic is sports, I know:

```
75% of sports documents have the word "play"
70% have the word "stadium"
40% have the word "contract"
30% have the word "baseball"
```

2) Given this, and a document with a bunch of words, how can I calculate the probability this document belongs to that topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fuzzy classification problem with topics as classes and words as features. Normally you don't have bag of words for each topic, but rather set of documents and associated topics, so I will describe this case first.

The most natural way to find probability (in the same sense it is used in probability theory) is to use **naive Bayes classifier**. This algorithm has been described many times, so I'm not going to cover it here. You can find quite good explanation in [this synopsis](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/naivebayes.pdf) or in associated [Coursera NLP lectures](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp).

There are also many other algorithms you can use. For example, your description naturally fits **[tf*idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)** based classifiers. tf*idf (term frequency * inverse document frequency) is a statistic used in modern search engines to calculate importance of a word in a document. For classification, you may calculate "average document" for each topic and then find how close new document is to each topic with [**cosine similarity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

If you have the case exactly like you've described - only topics and associated words - just consider each bag of words as a single document with, possibly, duplicating frequent words.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `topic modeling` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model) and if you are coding in python, you should check out radim's implementation, gensim (http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html). Otherwise there are many other implementations from http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html

Comment: +1 for the links, even though the question was not about topic modelling

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to solving a clustering problem. I suggest start with simple logistic regression and look at the results. If you already have predefined ontology sets, you can add them as features in next stage to improve accuracy.